# How can I define AccountId32 constant?

Tags: rust, substrate

I would like to define a constant with AccountId32 type.

The following code fails.

```
pub const RELAYER_A: AccountId32 = hex_literal::hex!["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"].into();
```

Error: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Probably `AccountId32(hex_literal::hex!["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"])`

Comment: `pub const ALICE: AccountId32 = AccountId32::new([1u8; 32]);`

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/contracts/src/tests.rs#L315